# "X is subject to Y" or "X is subjected to Y"?

Tags: grammaticality

> As with the current group term life insurance coverage these two new benefits are also considered to be non-cash taxable benefits and are ***subjected*** to statutory deductions for C\QPP contributions, income tax and NT/NU payroll taxes.

This is what I wrote in a school assignment, and was marked wrong.  The instructor says it should read, *taxable benefits are **subject** to statutory deductions*.  What is the correct grammar of this sentence please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["To be subject to" vs. "to be subjected to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45761/to-be-subject-to-vs-to-be-subjected-to)

Answer (score 5):

In this sentence, both *are subject to* and *are subjected to* are grammatical, and they mean two slightly different things. In the first, *subject* is an adjective, and in the second, it's a verb.

From Cambridge Dictionaries Online:

> [subject](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/subject_2) *adj.* often affected by something, especially something unpleasant,
>
> [subject to](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/subject-sb-sth-to-sth) *verb*: to make someone or something experience an unpleasant or worrying thing.

So somebody would be *subjected to* torture, but *subject to* depression.

The standard convention in English is to use the *adjective* for the meaning *subject to taxes*, even though the *often* in the definition above should be replaced by *almost always* in this case.

Comment: This is a helpful distinction because I hear the phrasal verb when I hear "subject to".

Comment: They're stressed differently . The causative verb is _subJECT to_  while the predicate adjective is _(be) SUBject to_. The auxiliary _be_ and the first syllable stress marks the adjective; second-syllable stress marks the verb. This is a very common pattern for two-syllable words that can be verbs or nouns/adjectives, depending on which syllable gets the stress. This only causes trouble in writing because English orthography is so inefficient.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a matter of using inconsistent tense to me. You are using the "-ed" suffix to make the word "subject" into what is called a past participle, [denoted as "pp." by Noah Webster](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=subjected&use1828=on) and then applying it to a sentence giving instructions to what must be done in either the present or the future, where a nominal adjective like the word [subject](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=subject&use1828=on) would be more consistent.