# Should we use subject or subjected?

Tags: prepositions

> general jurisdiction sessions. [5] Proponents of going
>   digital say that technology is the easiest way to get the
>   most accurate record of the proceedings, as the machine
>   records everything faithfully as it occurs and is not
>   [26] subject to human errors such as mishearing or
>   mistyping. [6] However, with the rise of high-quality
>   recording technology, reliance on court reporters 27 as a
>   record keeper is decreasing.

In the short excerpt above, the word following [26] will be *subject* or *subjected*. I think it should be *subjected*, but I am not really sure and can't convince myself why. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["To be subject to" vs. "to be subjected to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45761/to-be-subject-to-vs-to-be-subjected-to)

Answer (score 1):

You need the adjectival **subject to** here, because what you mean is “errors *are liable to* happen”.

You would only use the verbal **subjected to** to indicate that “as part of a systematic procedure, errors are *deliberately introduced*”.

These [definitions](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/subject) from the Oxford Dictionary online substanciate this:

**ADJECTIVE**

**Likely or prone to be affected by**
(a particular condition or occurrence, typically an unwelcome or unpleasant one)

*‘he was subject to bouts of manic depression’*

**VERB**

**subject someone/something to**
Cause or force someone or something to undergo (a particular experience or form of treatment, typically an unwelcome or unpleasant one)

*‘he'd subjected her to a terrifying ordeal’*