# What's the difference between "subject to" and "subjected to" in contracts?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases, legalese, nuance

> - Applicants are subject to testing ...
> - Applicants are subjected to testing ...

When employers use "subject to" or "subjected to" in this way, does "subject to" imply they can if they want to, i.e. there's a chance?

Does "subjected to" mean employees are required to take a drug test"?

Comment: *Subject to* means depending on, or based on. If you pass the test, you may be hired, but for sure that will depend on passing the test. The fact that you will be subjected to a drug test is not built into the wording. The only thing that is optional, like "They can if they want to/there's a chance", is hiring you after the test (which is not optional). Your test for drugs is not really a choice, only their choice to hire you *subject to* clean results.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So "Subject to"  means there may or may not be a test?

Comment: No, there is no maybe. If they are considering hiring you seriously, it still depends on the test. **You will be tested.** You will pee in a cup that will be tested for the expected body temperature. The only way that there "may or not be a test" is if they lose interest in hiring you, then No test.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["To be subject to" vs. "to be subjected to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45761/to-be-subject-to-vs-to-be-subjected-to)

Comment: Ah, this answer from that makes sense:                                                               Quick summary:
Subject to = might happen
Subjected to = did or will happen

Comment: Here's the problem: In the [original answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45761/to-be-subject-to-vs-to-be-subjected-to), **employees might be tested or not after they're hired** ("employees are subject to testing ... Means that at any time they could be required to be tested.)

Here, **applicants** will be tested — hiring them depends on the drug screen. Applicants **might** get hired, but there's **no might** be subject to testing.